# realloc throws "Access violation reading location"

Tags: c, visual-studio, memory, realloc

I'm using Visual Studio 16.6.0. 
In some part of my C program, I have a dynamic array (myvector), which I'm trying to resize to contain a a certain number of elements (variable numberofrecords). Using exactly the same input data, sometimes this code works, or it randomly throws "***Access violation reading location***" in the `realloc` execution.
My two questions:

1. If there is a problem with the `realloc`,  shouldn't the error control detect it as a returned NULL?
2. Most important: what I'm doing wrong? I'm sorry if this is a silly question, but I cannot find out why this realloc is throwing random exceptions even with exactly the same input time after time.

```
    void* temp; //temporal pointer for realloc
    int* myvector = malloc(sizeof(int));

    int numberofrecords = 0;


    while(numberofrecords<100){  

       if (some_condition){
          numberofrecords++;
          temp = realloc(myvector, numberofrecords * sizeof(int));
          if (temp == NULL) { 
              printf("ERROR in realloc\n");
              free(myvector);
              exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
          }
          else {
              myvector = temp;
          }          
       }
    }//while end
```

Thank you

Comment: My guess is the problem is really somewhere else, where you go out of bounds of the allocated memory. The code you show is, as you currently show it, is fine.

Comment: Replace `some_condition` with `1` and run this code stand-alone in a simple `main`. It should run without issue. That along should tell you the real problem lays in what you *have not* posted.

Comment: You say "input" but there are no input-consuming statements in your code. Do you mean the second argument of `realloc()`?

Comment: Also: What makes you feel so sure that the error occurs at `realloc()`? This kind of error message doesn´t belong to `realloc()` usally. Please provide the full error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as said by commenters above, it was due to realloc of strings not finished by '\0' appends some junk characters to the original string and it makes that appends to it get outbounds of the string size.

Thank you very much for your help